# why almalinux is hanging over night with auditlog

Tags: cron, audit, litespeed, whm, cloudlinux

hey there is  a hosting server
overnight my server hanged up and must  to restart it in morning to get it back online and saw this error in my console (you can see the picture)
please help me
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKwlF.png

Comment: You tagged your question whm. Are you using cPanel control panels? Do you have privilaged (root, console) access that is not through whm?

Comment: Yes it's whm + cloudlinux + litespeed